# Make Google app with javascript in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButtonText'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

I have this Javascript code.I want to convert it to an Extension(Chrome webapp for personal use).That is every time i click this in chrome browser. i want to execute this javascript.
How can i achieve this
so that i can avoid entering this code often in console.
Manifest.json

```
  1{                                                                           
  2           "manifest_version": 2,
  3 
  4                     "name": "blah",
  5                       "description": "blah blah",
  6                         "version": "1.0",
  7 
  8                           "browser_action": {
  9                                      "default_icon": "icon.png",
 10                                     "default_popup": "popup.html"
 11                                                   },
 12                             "permissions": [
 13                                        "activeTab"
 14                                           ],
 15                    "web_accessible_resources": [
 16                                          "popup.js"
 17                                                 ]
 18 }
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Congoroo</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HaAHAHAH</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Check this</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButtonText'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

code in popup.js works perfectly in Console of chrome.
but in this extension i made nothing happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest.json

```
{
      "name": "InviteThemAll",
            "version": "0.0.1",
              "manifest_version": 2,
                "description": "Invite all Friends in Fb to Fanpage",
              "homepage_url": "http://felixjosemon.github.io/",
                "background": {
                        "scripts": [
                              "background.js"
                                  ],
                        "persistent": true
                              },
                  "browser_action": {
                          "default_title": "FB!"
                            },
                    "permissions": [
                        "https://*/*",
                    "http://*/*",
                        "tabs"
                          ]
}
```

popup.js

```
(function() {

 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButtonText'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); } })();
```

background.js

```
// this is the background code...

// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
            // for the current tab, inject the "popup.js" file & execute it
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
                        file: 'popup.js'


    });
        });
```

After Lot of tries I made background.js to inject popup.js into current Tab and this works perfectly to my need.
Using this you can sent Invites to all your Fb friends to Like your Fanpage.
https://github.com/Felixjosemon/InviteThemAll